# Imported python xarray module's attributes aren't working

Tags: python, conda, python-xarray

I've installed Python's `xarray` module using

```
$ conda install xarray
```

After I import it and try and use an attribute it returns that xarray doesn't have the attribute I'm trying to call.

```py
import xarray as xr
filepath="users/____/file.nc"
DS = xr.open_mfdataset(filepath)
```

It returned the following error message:

```
AttributeError: module 'xarray' has no attribute 'open_mfdataset'
```

I am using Visual Studio Code with Python interface 3.6.9 64-bit ('base':conda)

Comment: Do you have `dask` installed as well?

Comment: Do you have a folder named "xarray" next to your script, or somewhere in your $PATH ?